# Disabling a button using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have created a button in VBA that adds text to a worksheet when pressed but I only want the user to be able to press it once so the text can be only added to the worksheet once. The button is called YesFogBandit and I added the code:

```
YesFogBandit.Enabled = False
```

At the end of the sub routine that the button is assigned to.

**Whole Sub routine:**

```
Sub FogBanditAddition()
    
    Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SpecSheet As Worksheet
    Dim VariablesSheet As Worksheet
    Dim FBInfo As Range
    Dim YesFogBandit As Button
    
    Set InputSheet = Worksheets("Input")
    Set SpecSheet = Worksheets("IntruderSpec")
    Set VariablesSheet = Worksheets("Variables")
    Set FBInfo = VariablesSheet.Range("FBInfo")
    Set YesFogBandit = InputSheet.Buttons("YesFogBandit")
    
    With SpecSheet
        SpecNext = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Row
        FBInfo.Copy
        .Cells(SpecNext, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllExceptBorders
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        .Range(Cells(SpecNext + 1, 1).Address(), Cells(SpecNext + 1, 4).Address()).RowHeight = 50
    End With

    YesFogBandit.Enabled = False

End Sub
```

This doesnt stop the button working and and the button still carries on as it worked before this code was added.
Please help.

Comment: There is no `button`-object in Excel. How did you create it? You should receive a compile error.

Comment: That's what I thought in the first place, too. But as soon as you add a form button on a sheet you will have it.

Comment: I used the form buttons and assigned the sub routine as a macro to it. The button does what I want when I click it but it does not deactivate after it has been pressed once.

Comment: Yes, because the property `Enabled` does not mean the same as with a Active-X button or a button on a userform. But right now I do not know how to deactivate resp. disable this kind of button

Comment: Would it work if I changed it to an Active-X button?

Comment: Yes, that would work but there should also be a possibilty to do it with a form button. Maybe `YesFogBandit.Visible = False` could work for you. But the button is "gone" then.

Comment: A workaround would be to add a second, non-functioning button with the same location and dimensions but 'behind' your main button. You could alter the colour etc. so that when the primary button is hidden, the overall effect is that it has become disabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
YesFogBandit.Visible = False
```

This worked as I then made the button reappear using a reset button that reset my project.